# Windows Phone 7 App, loading csv data into an app

Tags: csv, windows-phone-7, backup

I am writing an app which allows users to enter some data into their windows phone 7 device. Users can back up that data by emailing a copy of the data to themselves. Is there some mechanism that allows users to load the data (assume a CSV file) from an email attachment back into the app?

I would appreciate some pointers as to how I might go about reloading saved data back into the app.

Any other mechanism for syncing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct integration point between inbound email contents and launching an app at the moment.

To get a CSV into your app you could implement a web service that your app can query for files to be downloaded.

Comment: Hi Mick,  
Thank you for the reply. So every WP7 app that wants to sync data with the user's desktop now has to have a mini web-service running? <grin> Thanks microsoft!

Comment: No worries... if you felt like explaining your app's requirements on their suggestion forums it might help to influence future releases.